# Regex: search from a specific character boundary

Tags: regex

I'd like to search for instances of 'Charles I' within certain strings. I'm only interested in finding 'Charles I', not anything else (like 'xxx:' or 'statue of'):

```
XXX: Charles I           -> 1 
XXX: YYY: Charles I      -> 1 
Charles I                -> 1 
Statue of Charles I      -> 0 
XXX: Statue of Charles I -> 0
```

I've got as far as:

```
[.*?:] charles I$
```

But this only works with instances beginning with XXX: and not line initial. Please help.

Comment: please clarify, in your sample which lines should be found and which should not?

Comment: `(?<!\w )Charles I$`?

Comment: simply "\\bCharles\\sI\\b" should find each occurance

Comment: What language, and for what purpose? In JS `/\bCharles I\b/g` would do what you want, provided you just wanted to find all occurances

Comment: @heemayl - Thanks for this! I'm almost there now. 
How do I make it more specific? I'm only interested in the colon (e.g. XXX:) but this regex also captures XXX. or XXX;

Comment: Try `(?<=: )Charles I$`

Comment: @heemayl - that's much better. Now these are satisfied:

'XXX: Charles I'  and 'XXX: YYY: Charles I' 

But I want to also capture: 'Charles I', (but not 'Statue of Charles I')

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `(?<=: )Charles I$|^Charles I$`

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern says find a string that starting with ., *, ?, or :, followed by a space and charles I where an immediate end of line follows.  But I understand your requirement to be, find Charles I.  You are ambiguous as to whether you want to exclude Charles I that are preceded with "Statue of", or you just want to exclude "Statue of" from your result.  I will assume the latter.

That being the case

```
\\b[Cc]harles\\sI\\b
```

Should capture what you want.